# Making the child's input dependent on parent input value

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to

1. initialize the child's state with the parent's respective value. To do this, I set the child's state value in the constructor using the following code:
2. Reset the value of child as soon as the parent'
3. Retain the ability to change the child's value

To achieve the second goal, I use `getDerivedStateFromProps` the following way
https://codepen.io/jedgar-nawasardqn/pen/VRpWrZ?editors=1011

```
class Parent extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          value: "default valu"
        }
    }
    onChange = (value) => {
         this.setState({
              value: value
         })
    }

    render() {

      return (
          <div>
              <form>
                 <label>Parent: </label>
                 <input
                 value={this.state.value}
                 onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
              </form>
              <Child
                 value={this.state.value}/>
          </div>);
      }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          value: this.props.value
        }
    }
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
     console.log('nextProps', nextProps)   
     return {
            value: nextProps.value
        }
    }
  onChange = (value) => {
         console.log('CHild changed')
         this.setState({
              value: value
         })
    } 
  render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <label>Child: </label>
           <input
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
         </div>)
   }
}

React.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

...but for some reason I can't make it work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What's your second goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your goals of wanting to have a parent input control a child input when the parent changes, but allowing the child input to change itself and not affect the parent:

The problem is that `getDerivedStateFromProps` gets called regardless so when you are changing the state from the Child's input, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is immediately reverting it back to the Parent's value. You should use `componentDidUpdate` and diff the props rather than using `getDerivedStateFromProps` and only update the Child's state to match the Parent's when the Parent's state actually changes.

I made a Code Sandbox based on your Fiddle to demonstrate this: https://codesandbox.io/s/m5qj6qq769?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

First, even if it's not about your question, I suggest you to not use an arrow function inside the `render()` method, so, instead of writing `onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)} />`, you should just write `onChange={this.onChange} />`. The reason is that the arrow function would be created and then discarded at every `render()`: not a big deal if we have few renders and few arrow functions, but.. It's better to avoid waste of computational power :)

Now, about your question! Honestly, it seems that the `Child` Component just need to show the value, thus, it's not really useful to "copy" the value from `Parent` Component to `Child` Component: you can just keep your values in the `Parent` Component, and then refers to that value in both `Parent` and `Child` Component. 
To do this, you need to pass an handler function also to the `Child` Component.
Let's look at the fiddle!

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>Child: </label>
                <input
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {value: "Default Value"};
    }
    
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label>Parent: </label>
                        <input
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </form>
                <Child
                    value={this.state.value}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```